# why 1 // 0.05 results in 19.0 in python?

Tags: python, floating-accuracy

I'm a new to python and I found a confusing result when using Python3.5.1 on my mac, I simply ran this command in my terminal

```
    1 // 0.05
```

However, it printed 19.0 on my screen. From my point of view, it should be 20. Can someone explain what's happening here? I've already known that the '//' is similar to the math.floor() function. But I still can't get across to this.

Comment: It divides then rounds down. That is about it.

Comment: @MarkyPython: There's more to it than that.  On my machine, `1 / 0.05` is `20.0`, but `1 // 0.05` is `19.0`.

Comment: Long story short: don't *expect* any particular result when dealing with floating point numbers.

Comment: Why was this reopened? IMO [Is floating point math broken?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/588004/2301450) was a good dupe target.

Comment: Huh, I thought `//` is supposed to return `int`...

Comment: @vaultah I reopened it because I don't consider it to be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/588004/2301450 . This question is specifically about how the floor division operator works. It's not a generic question about why floating point math is imprecise.

Comment: Why is there can't you pydoc this and operators in general `pydoc(//)`

Comment: @GingerPlusPlus you thought wrong. Just as with other numeric operations the type of the result is determined by the types of the operands. It can return `int`, `float`, `Decimal`, `complex` and so on.

Comment: @surfer190: You _can_ do `pydoc '//'` or `help('//')`, although I admit the result is of limited usefulness, apart from the precedence info.

Comment: For exact **decimal** fractions you should be using `decimal.Decimal`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because the Python floating-point literal `0.05` represents a number very slightly larger than the mathematical value 0.05.

```
>>> '%.60f' % 0.05
'0.050000000000000002775557561562891351059079170227050781250000'
```

`//` is floor division, meaning that the result is the largest integer `n` such that `n` times the divisor is less than or equal to the dividend. Since 20 times 0.05000000000000000277555756156289135105907917022705078125 is larger than 1, this means the correct result is 19.

As for *why* the Python literal `0.05` doesn't represent the number 0.05, as well as many other things about floating point, see [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Comment: Also, it does not return an *integer* in this case, but float.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala: I did wonder whether I'd get away with that terminology. It returns a floating-point value that represents an integer. What it doesn't return, is the Python type `int` (or `long`), but I'm using the word "integer" here to mean the mathematical concept of an integer, not the Python type called `int`.

Comment: @SteveJessop Thanks for your help, I really should have been careful with floating-point value in programming.

Answer (score 3):

0.05 is not exactly representable in floating point. `"%0.20f" % 0.05` shows that 0.05 is stored as a value very slightly greater than the exact value:

```
>>> print "%0.20f" % 0.05
0.05000000000000000278
```

On the other hand `1/0.05` does appear to be exactly 20:

```
>>> print "%0.20f" % (1/0.05)
20.00000000000000000000
```

However all floating point values are rounded to double when stored but calculations are done to a higher precision. In this case it seems the floor operation performed by `1//0.05` is done at full internal precision hence it is rounded down.

Answer (score 1):

As the previous answerers have correctly pointed out, the fraction 0.05 = 1/20 cannot be exactly represented with a finite number of base-two digits.  It works out to the repeating fraction 0.0000 1100 1100 1100... (much like 1/3 = 0.333... in familiar base-ten).

But this is not quite a complete answer to your question, because there's another bit of weirdness going on here:

```
>>> 1 / 0.05
20.0
>>> 1 // 0.05
19.0
```

Using the “true division” operator `/` happens to give the expected answer `20.0`. You got lucky here: The rounding error in the division exactly cancels out the error in representing the value 0.05 itself.

But how come `1 // 0.05` returns 19?  Isn't `a // b` supposed to be the same as `math.floor(a /b)`?  Why the inconsistency between `/` and `//`?

Note that the `divmod` function is consistent with the `//` operator:

```
>>> divmod(1, 0.05)
(19.0, 0.04999999999999995)
```

This behavior can be explained by performing computing the floating-point division with exact rational arithmetic.  When you write the literal `0.05` in Python (on an IEEE 754-compliant platform), the actual value represented is 3602879701896397 / 72057594037927936 = 0.05000000000000000277555756156289135105907917022705078125.  This value happens to be slightly **more** than the intended 0.05, which means that its reciprocal will be slightly **less**.

To be precise, 72057594037927936 / 3602879701896397 = 19.999999999999998889776975374843521206126552300723564152465244707437044687...

So, `//` and `divmod` see an integer quotient of 19.  The remainder works out to 0.04999999999999994726440633030506432987749576568603515625, which is rounded for display as `0.04999999999999995`.  So, the `divmod` answer above is in fact good to 53-bit accuracy, given the original incorrect value of `0.05`.

But what about `/`?  Well, the true quotient 72057594037927936 / 3602879701896397 isn't representable as a `float`, so it must be rounded, either down to `20-2**-48` (an error of about 2.44e-15) or up to `20.0` (an error of about 1.11e-15).  And Python correctly picks the more accurate choice, `20.0`.

So, it seems that Python's floating-point division is internally done with high enough precision to know that `1 / 0.05` (that's the `float` literal `0.05`, not the exact decimal fraction 0.05), is actually **less** than 20, but the `float` type in itself is incapable of representing the difference.

At this point you may be thinking “So what?  I don't care that Python is giving a correct reciprocal to an incorrect value.  I want to know how to get the correct value in the first place.”  And the answer to that is either:

- [`decimal.Decimal('0.05')`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html) (and don't forget the quotes!)
- [`fractions.Fraction('0.05')`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fractions.html) (Of course, you may also use the numerator-denominator arguments as `Fraction(1, 20)`, which is useful if you need to deal with non-decimal fractions like 1/3.)